# Why does opstring not create the expected response when using getopt in c?

Tags: c++, c, getopt

I am trying to write a getopt() module for a program I am writing and for some Reason my use of getopt() is not working.

```
#include "setopt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct flags_t getFlags(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct flags_t ourflags;
    int opt;

    ourflags.threadpool = 4;

    while (1) {
        opt = getopt(argc, argv, "N:l:");
        if (opt == -1) {
            //printf("getting bad read -1\n");
            break;
        }

        switch (opt) {
            case 'l' : 
                strcpy(ourflags.logfilename, optarg);
                break;
            case 'N' : 
                ourflags.threadpool = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            default :
                printf("unkown flag %c\n", opt);
                exit(-1);
        }


    }

    const int requiredargs = 1;

    if (argc - optind != requiredargs) {
        printf("incorrect amount of flags, wanted : %d: got %d\n", 
                        requiredargs, (argc - optind));
        exit(-1);
    }

    ourflags.port = atoi(argv[optind]);

    return ourflags;
}
```

When I run my program using

```
./setopt 8080 -N 6 -l log_file
```

I get the output

```
incorrect amount of flags, wanted : 1: got 5
```

I think the problem is in my optstring argument, But I am not sure. I cannot get he switch cases to take. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try putting the `8080` after the options?

Comment: That works, but why does it not when the non-option args are in the front?

Comment: You should print which parameter was recognized and consumed. Also print the numbers. You might well find that no option was recognized at all.

Comment: This is not an implementation of `getopt` It is a _use_ of the implementation that shipped with your computer/compiler.

Comment: changed it to "use" for you

Comment: When reading the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) did you see the paragraph mentioning `POSIXLY_CORRECT`?

Comment: I did. I tried to set my optstring as "-N:l:" and then using the 1 character. as a result, none of the flags were being read.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. I am running the program using terminal on my MacBook. When I run the program using Ubuntu 18.04, the program works as expected. Is there a command that I can put into my Mac that can get the expected results?

Comment: Maybe unset `POSIXLY_CORRECT` before calling the program? When I use `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` and run your program, I get same error. `optind==1` in that case. When I use `unset POSIXLY_CORRECT` and call again, I get `optind==4`. In any case `argv[optind]` pointed to `"8080"` afterwards